# Image Cover Flow in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am using AFOpenFlow to display images. Now i want to display same things in landscape mode. I want to display all images like this:[image]

Anybody have an idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an idea though but not in AFOpenFlow

Comment: Can you share your idea may be it will help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest, you try [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) of Nick Lockwood, it has the features you need, make it vertical, then add the images you wanted to put in it. And it can be in Landscape because I already have tried it.